# Create daily log script in linux

Tags: linux, logging, scripting

I am trying to write a script that will generate a daily log file but currently, log file appends all the log in one file which is test.log. I am able to generate test.log with date extension but it just changes the date and the log inside test.log has all days log how can I write a script which will give me daily log generation with date extension.

```
NOW=$(date +"%F")
LOG_DIR=$OO_LOCAL{log-dir}
#CONSOLE_LOG="$OO_LOCAL{console-log}-$NOW.log"
CONSOLE_LOG="/log/springboot/test-$NOW.log"
TMP_DIR=$DIR/tmp
JAR_FILE="/app/$OO_LOCAL{artifact-id}/current/$OO_LOCAL{artifact-id}-$OO_LOCAL{artifact-version}.jar"

CMD="java $JAVA_OPTS $DISABLE_JIT -Djava.io.tmpdir=$TMP_DIR -jar $JAR_FILE 2>&1 >> $CONSOLE_LOG & echo \$! >$PIDFILE"
```

output
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  8453324 Jun 30 11:38 test-2020-06-29.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 11864615 Jul  2 15:36 test-2020-06-30.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1179215 Jul  3 12:25 test-2020-07-02.log

Comment: NOW=$(date +"%F")
LOG_DIR=$OO_LOCAL{log-dir}
#CONSOLE_LOG="$OO_LOCAL{console-log}-$NOW.log"
CONSOLE_LOG="/log/springboot/intl-e2e-sc-visibility-kpi-$NOW.log"
TMP_DIR=$DIR/tmp
JAR_FILE="/app/$OO_LOCAL{artifact-id}/current/$OO_LOCAL{artifact-id}-$OO_LOCAL{artifact-version}.jar"

PROG="$OO_LOCAL{name}"
PIDFILE="$OO_LOCAL{pid-location}"                                                                                              i am new to this not sure how can i setup a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it would help if you produced a complete example as there are variables the definition of which are not readily apparent.  In your CMD line, you are using an append operator instead of an overwrite operator (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64374/difference-between-and-operators)), but that's only part of the problem.  You should begin by looking into the creation and testing of cron jobs for any events which you'd like to have recur.  See [cron jobs](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/set-up-cron-job-linux), and [properly testing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42715/how-can-i-make-cron-run-a-job-right-now-for-testing-debugging-without-changing) a cron job.

Here is how, in the past, I have dated files.  These lines belong to a file which is part of a script that is run by a cron job, nightly.

```
# get current directory name
ABSDIR=`pwd`
DIR=`basename $ABSDIR`
# form the name of the tarball from the directory name and the date
TBNAME="$DIR"-`date +"%F.%H.%M.%S"`.tgz
```

The script itself is one that I employ frequently when I want to create tarballs that are timestamped.

Some people may not like this format, in which case, you can convert the back-ticks to $() such as:

```
# get current directory name
ABSDIR=$(pwd)
DIR=$(basename $ABSDIR)
# form the name of the tarball from the directory name and the date
TBNAME="$DIR"-$(date +"%F.%H.%M.%S").tgz
```

Comment: I have the output file but its getting appended daily but i want to create a new file daily with date on it. Any idea how to achieve that?

here is the existing script